# Is it possible to append data to JSON file?

Tags: python, json, serialization, pickle

I am generating some arrays for a simulation and I want save them in a JSON file. I am using the jsonpickle library.

The problem is that the arrays I need to save can be very large in size (hundreds of MB up to some GB). Thus, I need to save each array to the JSON file immediately after its generation.

Basically, I am generating a multiple independent large arrays, storing them in another array and saving them into the JSON file after all of them have been generated:

```
N = 1000 # Number of arrays 
z_NM = np.zeros((64000,1), dtype=complex) # Large array
z_NM_array = np.zeros((N,64000,1), dtype=complex) # Array of z_NM arrays

for in range(0, N):
   z_NM[:,0] = GenerateArray() # Generate array and store it in z_NM_array
   z_NM_array[i] = z_NM

# Write data to JSON file
data = {"z_NM_array": z_NM_array}
outdata = json.encode(data)
with open(filename, "wb+") as f:
    f.write(outdata.encode("utf-8"))
    f.close()
```

I was wondering if it is instead possible to append the new data to the existing JSON file, by writing each array to the file immediately after its generation, inside the for loop? If so, how? And how can it be read back? Maybe using a library different from jsonpickle?

I know I could save each array in a separate file, but I'm wondering if there's a solution that lets me use a single file. I also have some settings in the dict which I want to save along with the array.

Comment: When you say "JSON pickle" do you mean [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/) or something else? I suspect JSON libraries typically won't support writing an array element by element, because this would mean that until you are done and manually finalize your file its syntax is broken, and it would not be possible to read any of that data. But I'm not familiar with jsonpickle.

Comment: @Deak Yes, I mean jsonpickle.

Comment: You should still [edit] and clarify your question a bit. Do you have one large array that you want to print element by element? Or indeed independent arrays? A small example of what your data is _shaped_ like and how you imagine the file to be constructed should make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I've added clarifications. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I understand it a bit more what you're trying to do, but I'm getting more confused about your intended behaviour :) On the top level what you're trying to print is a _dict_, where the multidimensional array is a _value_. If you were to write those arrays in batches, that would involve printing a beginning of the dict (an "object" in JSON lingo) and somehow printing _some_ of the multidimensional array. It's also more complicated because instead of a collection of arrays you technically have a single multidimensional array, so more care has to be taken with printing...

Comment: And my other issue is that in your example all the large array is in memory, yet you want to cut down on memory use. Do I understand correctly that you basically want to move the JSON printing inside the `for i in range(N)` loop where you create each 2d array? And if so, do you understand how that's sort of incompatible with you trying to export a _dict_ containing the large 3d array?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, I want to move JSON printing inside the for loop, to reduce memory usage. It is not a problem if it is incompatible. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I have very little practical experience with JSON and zero with jsonpickle, so my experience here doesn't help much (though I'd be surprised if this were possible). But taking a step back: do you really need JSON, or just some kind of serialization? If you are only mainly printing arrays I'd go for [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am saving other settings along with the arrays, so JSON was easy to work with, but I can try numpy.save.

Comment: The downside of `numpy.save` that it only saves arrays, so it can get messy if your settings are not numeric. You _can_ save object arrays with it, but that needs pickle which makes it vulnerable if malicious people can have access to your saved data before you read it back.

Comment: Do you want the file to contain *one* single valid JSON that grows, or *several* valid JSON that come one after the other? Is there a reason why you are not using CSV, which is very easy to append to?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My intention was to use one single JSON file that grows. But I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I recommend looking at plain ``pickle`` if you do not need language interoperability, ``csv`` if you do not need performance, and HDF5 in any other case.